# Could not resolve all files for configuration classpath

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, gradlew

A problem occurred configuring root project 'My Application'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
> Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.1.1.
> Required by:
> project : > com.android.application:com.android.application.gradle.plugin:8.1.1
> > No matching variant of com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.1.1 was found. The consumer was configured to find a library for use during runtime, compatible with Java 8, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally, as well as attribute 'org.gradle.plugin.api-version' with value '8.0' but:
> - Variant 'apiElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.1.1 declares a library, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
> - Incompatible because this component declares a component for use during compile-time, compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed a component for use during runtime, compatible with Java 8
> - Other compatible attribute:
> - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.0')
> - Variant 'javadocElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.1.1 declares a component for use during runtime, and its dependencies declared externally:
> - Incompatible because this component declares documentation and the consumer needed a library
> - Other compatible attributes:
> - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8)
> - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
> - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.0')
> - Variant 'runtimeElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.1.1 declares a library for use during runtime, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
> - Incompatible because this component declares a component, compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed a component, compatible with Java 8
> - Other compatible attribute:
> - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.0')
> - Variant 'sourcesElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.1.1 declares a component for use during runtime, and its dependencies declared externally:
> - Incompatible because this component declares documentation and the consumer needed a library
> - Other compatible attributes:
> - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8)
> - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
> - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.0')

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

I try to build apk using comandline in androidstudio